# Shouldn't there be an image for the community?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, design

I suggest that we use an image of many balls from diferent sports. Also I think it would be nice if the name was Faul Challenge, as if in a game there was a faul, but someone challenges it and its necessary to ask someone about the sport's rules.

Comment: The name of what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a [beta site](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta), we don't get a custom image. If we want to get a custom image, theme and the like we'd have to meet the graduation criteria and become a fully fledged site.

Comment: Coincidentally, the beta status changed shortly after this question: [Congratulations, you're no longer in Beta!](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/937)

Comment: @Martin I did see that :-) However, with 28 sites "graduating" at once, it's not be instantaneously that we get a custom theme/image etc.